# C++ why cannot assign an object created inside constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, global-variables

due project's requirements, by this week I'm shifted from Java to C++. I'm facing a lot of trouble, but maybe the greater is the "pass-by-value" and... obviously pointers :)
Now I have a big doubt regard the destiny of an object instantiated inside an the constructor of another object. Here my simple  SSCCE composed by an header and a cpp file:

```
#pragma once
#include <map>
class MapReferenceHolder
{
    std::map<int, char*>* mapPointer;
public:
    MapReferenceHolder();
    ~MapReferenceHolder();
    void setMap(std::map<int,char*>* map);
    void addSomeElementToMap();
    void MapReferenceHolder::printMap();
};
```

Here the cpp file containing the main:

```
#include "MapReferenceHolder.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

std::map<int, char*>mymap;
MapReferenceHolder::MapReferenceHolder()
{
    setMap(&mymap);
}


MapReferenceHolder::~MapReferenceHolder()
{
}

void MapReferenceHolder::setMap(std::map<int, char*>* map){
    mapPointer = map;
}

void MapReferenceHolder::addSomeElementToMap(){

    (*mapPointer)[0] = "stringONe";
    (*mapPointer)[1] = "stringTwo";

}

void MapReferenceHolder::printMap(){
    std::map<int, char*>::iterator it = mapPointer->begin();
    while (it!=mapPointer->end()){
        cout << it->first << " -> " << it->second << "\n";
        it++;
    }
}

int main(){

    MapReferenceHolder m;
    m.addSomeElementToMap();
    m.printMap();


    cin.get();
    return 0;

}
```

This simple example run without problem. But if I move the mymap instantiation inside the constructor, i.e.

```
MapReferenceHolder::MapReferenceHolder()
{
    std::map<int, char*>mymap;
    setMap(&mymap);
}
```

I get thw folowing error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00B2BD3B in Project1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCD0.
```

I guess this is due to the fact that an instance of an object live only inside the block in which  is defined. But I'm passing the address of object, so it is still alive!?? Or the compiler destroy it in any case? And more important... is it, then, right create a global variable to store an object instance. How I can use correctly the constructor? I know this is a "newbie" question but I'm try to match  project's development needs and my spare time to study is really little. Any help will be great appreciated.
Regards, 
microvo

Comment: Are you sure there isn't an extra `*` in this line: `std::map<int, char*>* mapPointer;`?

Comment: Isn't a constant string say "hello" a pointer to the first char?

Comment: Can you explain why you even do this in the constructor? It does not seem to make much point from a design perspective. A map reference holder should refer to some external map, not have a default internal map that may or may not be in use.

Comment: thanks for the reply Matt. This is only an SSCCE code for ask a simple question. This isn't code designed to work in the real world.

Answer (score 3):

The object is destroyed at the end of the constructor. so you have saved a pointer that is no longer valid.

Comment: Thanks. As I supposed. But then is more correct set a global variable or is better declare the instance inside the header?

Comment: @microvo: Who owns the object and is responsible for destroying it? That determines where you create the variable.

Comment: @John3136 There is a code fragment in which mymap is created on the stack in the constructor. That one is not global.

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider ownership in C++ (Java has a cycle detecting garbage collector so gives you a lot of leeway).

If `MapReferenceHolder` owns the `std::map` you should make it a value rather than a pointer, you can always use a reference to it if you need a pointer for some reason. Also get rid of your constructor and destructor unless they contain actual code.

Alternatively you could call `delete mapPointer` in your destructor but that is adding extra code for no benefit in simple cases like this IMO.

If `MapReferenceHolder` does not own `std::map` then you need to require the pointer be passed in and somehow track the lifetime of it somewhere outside this class.

Answer (score 0):

The map object no longer exists once it goes out of scope, regardless of any pointers that hold its address - these are no longer valid. I suggest a search for "constructor initializer list" might help you.